# Excel VBA: This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: excel, vba

**Objective:**

I have a few variables that I've declared as variants and I want to add them to a dictionary so I can loop through them and add values to them dynamically. I would like them initialized with the value of Null because I'll be passing them into a sql statement later where they need to be Null if there is no value available. The values will come from a range of cells in Excel.

**Error:**

> Run-time error '457':
>
> This key is already associated with an element
>   of this collection

**Code:**

```
Dim Entity As Variant
Dim Project As Variant
Dim Status As Variant
Dim Draft As Variant
...

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

d.Add Entity, Null
d.Add Project, Null <- Debugger highlights this row
d.Add Status, Null
d.Add Draft, Null
...
```

**What I've Tried:**

- [Casting the key, values as a string w/**CSTR()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050941/vb6-dictionary-this-key-is-already-associated-with-an-element-of-this-collection)

Comment: The values of the 4 variants must be unique, if you do not assign a value they will all be added as empty and so the second add will fail as an empty key already exists. (If your thinking that a unique variable is a unique key, that's not how it works).

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you, that makes sense. Would you happen to have an alternative approach where I could assign these variables null values and then use them in a loop?

Comment: Keys are usually strings: `d.Add "Entity", Null` / `read_value = d("Entity")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution:**

Add the keys as strings and then do any logic. Afterwards, pass the values from the dictionary back into a variable to use.

**Code:**

```
Dim Entity As Variant
Dim Project As Variant
Dim Status As Variant
Dim Draft As Variant
...

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

d.Add "Entity", Null
d.Add "Project", Null
d.Add "Status", Null
d.Add "Draft", Null
...

' Pass the values into the variable after manipulation
Entity = d("Entity")
Project = d("Project")
Status = d("Status")
Draft = d("Draft")
```